# add array to pandas data frame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have here an issue and would like to ask for support

Suppose you have a following frame

```
frame=pd.Dataframe({"Arbitary Number":[1,2,3,4]})
```

I want to add an additional column, whose entries are np.arrays. I add the entry the following way

```
frame["new col"]='[8,8,8,8]'
```

How ever in a later stage I need the entries as array. If I apply

```
frame["new col"]=frame["new col"].appy(np.array)
```

I still get object as column type and cannot use the entries to do some math work. I need to go the way with

```
np.array([eval(xxx)])
```

to have an array

The question is: Is there a nice and clean way to add arrays as column values without transforming them as strings before assigning them as value? 
Or if this is not the case and I do need to assign the list as string, is there a way to change the column type to np.array format? 
My mentioned solution is not working

Thanks a lot for any kind of help

Cheers

Comment: that's because your adding an object not an integer based list? try doing `df['new col'].map(eval)`

Comment: [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: `frame["new col"]=[np.array([8,8,8,8])]*frame.shape[0]`

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)